# File/folder permission error on hosts file in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, permission-denied

I have a problem with file permission in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\host` folder. it didn't let me to access the folder but i changed the folder permissions on the properties so that i can access the file now. but i don't want to manually access the file. i have a program and i want to let that program access the file to edit or modify it. i did everything i could but still can't let that program access the hosts file.

This is the current permissions on my "etc" folder:

```
Trustinstaller: full control
Users: full control
Administrator: full control
Mm (my username): full control
SYSTEM: full control
CREATOR OWNER: special permissions
ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES: full control
```

The same applies to the "hosts" file in that folder. i also tried to set the owner of the file and folder both to my username and "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES". still getting the same error. i also should mention that when i try to give full control of the "etc" folder to the "CREATOR OWNER" i get this error:

> an error occurred while applying security information to:
>   `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.ics`
>   Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied

Here is the error i get when i run the program as administrator:

> Unhandled exception has occured in your application. if you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click quit, the application will close immediately.

Access to path `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` is denied

I've used [lockhunter](http://www.lockhunter.com) to unlock "etc" folder but still i get that error. **i didn't have this problem before, it just happened today.** i disabled Kaspersky internet security, Windows defender and Firewall when i tried to use the application.

here is the full detail text:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
   at Hotspot_Shield_Elite_Universal_Crack.Form1.Button3_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Hotspot Shield Elite Universal Crack
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Mm/Desktop/Hotspot%20Shield%20Elite%20Universal%20Crack.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.20806.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34239 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34243 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: You set permissions on the *folder*, but did you ever set permissions on the *file*?

Comment: Yes, i also did the same thing on the file. please see the updates in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I found a link to fix this FROM THE COMMAND LINE.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-when/6e886d51-96fa-44b8-b687-3cf4fab619c2

pasted below to avoid dead link syndrome

you'll be running the commands below as "you" as the administrator....but this will enable you to give permissions to other accounts

c. From the results, right click Command Prompt and Click Run as Administrator.

d. At the command prompt, type “

```
takeown /f <foldername> /r /d y
```

” without quotes and then press ENTER. (Replace  with the path of the folder).

e. Then, type “

```
icacls <foldername> /grant administrators:F /T
```

” without quotes and hit enter. (Replace  with the path of the folder).

Comment: It looks like SO sanitized granadaCoder's input and removed the folder token.  I'll attempt to show the folder in the syntax:

Comment: ```takeown /f <folder> /r /d y```

Comment: ```icacls <folder> /grant administrators:F /T```

Comment: ah, thanks V-V.  I copied it exactly (originally) but now have put 'code delimiters' around code portions to avoid SO-santitation.